# Can you find any application for this result?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

Starting on Fermats Theorem, for $p$ prime, $a>1$ and $mcd(a,p)=1$
$$a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$$
Then elevating to $p-1$
$$(a^p)^{p-1}\equiv a^{p-1}\pmod{p}\equiv1\pmod{p}$$
Then by elevating to $(p-2)!$
$$(a^{p(p-1)})^{(p-2)!}\equiv1^{(p-2)!}\pmod{p}\equiv1\pmod{p}$$
We arrive to:
$$a^{p!}\equiv1\pmod{p}$$
And in general:
$$a^{k!}\equiv1\pmod{p}$$ for $k>p-2$

I think its a beautiful result cause it combines number theory and combinatorics, but does it have any application?

Comment: But $a^{m} \equiv 1 (\mbox{mod}\,p)$ whenever $m$ is a multiple of $p-1$. So what's so special about $m = p!$?

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately, as written you're just dressing up the fact $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ when $(a,p)=1$; I doubt there is any added value in doing so.

There is a related trick that *is* important: $p-1$ is a composite number, and you can have $(p-1) \mid k!$ for values of $k$ that are *much smaller than* $p-1$. And if you do, you still have $a^{k!} \equiv 1 \bmod p$.

This is the basis of a simple version of [Pollard's $p-1$ algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm). (in reality, there are better choices for the exponents than factorials, but the algorithm is still often presented using them)

Comment: your answer **is** a nice bit of added value.

Comment: to articulate the point more here, n! has power potentially higher than $x^{\lfloor {n\over x}\rfloor}$  in it's divisors for x<n. For primes like 19 or 31 of form 6y+1, where k is a smaller prime, or composed of small prime factors, you get that  6! divides by 18 and 5! divides by 30 respectively.